# git checkout doesn't do what it's supposed

Tags: git

I cloned a repository (the [linux-socfpga](https://github.com/altera-opensource/linux-socfpga)) and did some changes in `make menuconfig` without commiting. Now I want to discard my changes. I did `git checkout .` which does nothing.

I would like easy things to be easy but git makes the easy tasks impossible.

Wherever I read for instructions it just says do `git checkout .` but it does nothing. My changes are still there.

Comment: Did what changes?

Comment: *"did some changes in make menuconfig without commiting. Now I want to discard my changes."* -- [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) tells how to prepare your changes for commit and how to discard them.

Comment: @axiac It isn't intuitive at all. It is better to be simple.

Comment: What is not intuitive? The message displayed by `git status`? It tells you exactly what to do: *"use `git checkout -- <file>...` to discard changes in working directory"*. Or running `git status`? It is a basic command you should run before anything else, to know where you start from.

Comment: @axiac Easy tasks should be easy. It is better to be simple than to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git checkout .` only cleans tracked files. The configuration is `.config`, which isn't a part of source.

Try `git clean -xfd` to cleanup untracked files.

Comment: It works! Thanks.

Comment: Being 4k rep, I believe you know the proper way to say thanks by accepting the answer.

Comment: I may accept the answer in 6 minutes. There is some time limit. Thanks for the prompt help.